# Is this an animation workspace bug in 2.8?

Tags: camera, workspaces

When in Animation Workspace and I get out of Camera view everything disappears. This isn't happening in other files, but I can't find anything I've added that would make it do this. I've removed most everything but the lights and it still does this in this file. It's not clipping. It's not Show in Viewports checked off. This only happens in the Animation Workspace. All other workspaces including Layout are working fine.

[image: Cursor moved > disappears]

Comment: Please check if this also occurs in Blender 2.82. If it does, create a bug report through *Help > Report a Bug* in Blender and attach the project file.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this cause what you're seeing there, but your clip settings are pretty extreme, and I know that having Clip End too large, or Clip Start too small, can cause viewport problems. Your End is too large, and Start is too small!

Try End at 500, and start at 1.0. When you get into the perspective view, hit the home key to frame up the scene. Maybe that will work.